# Rspec testing global exception handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery
    rescue_from Exception, :with => :handle_exception

    private         
    def handle_exception
      render :template => "shared/500", layout: false
    end
end
```

Well i need to test above code with rspec.

I have tried, [testing anonymous controller](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller#specify-error-handling-in-applicationcontroller) and this is what i have according to it

```
require 'spec_helper'

     describe ApplicationController do
      controller do
        def index
          raise Exception
        end
      end

      describe "handling exceptions" do
        it "renders 500 template" do
          get :index
          expect(response).to render_template("shared/500")
        end
      end
    end
```

It is failing , what have i missed or please suggest a better way to test it?

Comment: What's the error you're getting ? or at least what's exactly failing ?

Comment: @pjam, I just closed everything and re ran the test.. 'It worked' with same... dunno what was wrong.. i was trying earlier for more than an hour :/

Comment: Well, that's some good news :)